# Root finding: zeroes of Mathieu function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, implementation-details

I am finding the roots of the Mathieu sine function, and find *Mathematica* and Maple do not agree on the solutions.

For example, consider the solutions of `Abs[MathieuS[4x, 4, Pi]] = 0`, for `2 < x < 3`.

*Mathematica* finds the solutions `x=2.31536` and `x=2.66776`, whereas Maple only agrees with the solution `x=2.31536`.

I show plots from *Mathematica* (top) and Maple (bottom) illustrating the disagreement.

[image: Mathematica plot of Mathieu function]

[image: Maple plot of Mathieu function]

Why are the results inconsistent?

Comment: You may want to try `Plot[{Re@#, Im@#} &@MathieuS[4 x, 4, Pi], {x, 2, 3}, Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: I guess their definition of Mathieu functions are different. For example, the Mathie characteristic functions in maple only take integer argument, but in Mathematica it takes real argument. I tried but [never figure out the differences](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/911608/49028).

Comment: for special functions, you need to make sure software uses the definition you expect, as for some special functions they can use slightly different definition. So you need to look up Maple definition of  Mathieu and compare that to Mathematica to make sure which one you want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Maple definition seems to be based on a different initial value for the derivative than the *Mathematica* definition.  The derivative of the Maple function SE(a, q, z] at z = 0 is 1; *Mathematica* has a different initial value. (I couldn't find a specification in the documentation or on functions.wolfram.com). Howevever, since they satisfy the same linear differential equation, they are constant multiples of one another.  You can divide the *Mathematica* one by its derivative at zero.

```
Plot[Abs[MathieuS[4 x, 4, Pi]/MathieuSPrime[4 x, 4, 0]], {x, 2, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]